# error: incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arrays

As you can see in below code, I am trying to add two (2-D integer ARRAYS),I know that variable (c) in the first method is a reference to the array , why can not I return that array or it's reference , Can I return 2-D array in general ,how?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Matrix_Addition {

    public static int sum (int[][]a,int[][]b){
        int[][]c=new int [a.length][b[1].length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
        return c;
    }
    public static void display(int[][]a){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][]a={{1,2,3},
                  {4,5,6},
                  {7,8,9}};

        int[][]b={{9,8,7}
                 ,{6,5,4},
                  {3,2,1}};

        int[][]c=sum(a,b);
        display(a);
        display(c);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the same type, as you have on input. `public static int[][] sum(int[][] a, int[][] b)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

c is an array/matrix but you try to return an int, try

```
public static int[][] sum (int[][]a,int[][]b) {
```

In general you should specificy in which line java tells you the error appears when asking a question.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have declared **c** as a 2-D array `(int[][]c=new int [a.length][b[1].length])`

Your sum method returns **int** and you are trying to return int 2-D array so it is giving you an error that incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int

You should change return type to your sum method from int to int[][].

```
public static int[][] sum (int[][]a,int[][]b){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same type as on input:

```
public static int[][] sum(int[][] a, int[][] b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you main function this line of code..

```
int[][]c=sum(a,b);
```

with

```
int c=sum(a,b);
```

and all the downline code like this...

```
display(a);
display(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

this will works. because if you see your `add()` function definition

```
public static int sum (int[][]a,int[][]b){.....} // return type is int not int[][].
```

> Reason : Return type of `sum(int[][], int[][])` is `int` not `int[][]`.